# p:sticky not working in p:dialog

Tags: primefaces

I can't seem to make p:sticky work inside a p:dialog :

my dialog xhtml :

```
<p:dialog modal="true" height="490" width="700" resizable="false"  >
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:toolbar id="tb">
            <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                <p:commandButton value="save"  />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>
        <p:sticky target="form:tb"     />
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

It works fine from a simple page. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, it is just not supported. And due to a 'bad' issue report, it is closed as invalid http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6341

Looking at the javascript source code of the sticky component, it checks scrolling of the window and not any other part inside it. So there is a big chance it will also fail in e.g. a p:layout.

Comment: I see.. any idea how to get the same behavior in a dialog?

Comment: Sure, multiple ways: download the source, change it and you that version or go PrimeFaces PRO and have them fix it for you, ask others to fix it for you, check if there is a simple plain jquery solution or just file an issue and wait… Filing an issue would be good anyway.  One solution is quicker than another but also more expensive (either in the short or long run)